# Get text position in textview

Tags: android, textview

How do I get the position of the last character in a Android... **TextView**, someone suggested `paintObj.measureText()`, and I have tried that but that only provides the width.

Comment: What do you mean by position? Maybe explain what you will be doing with the last character...

Comment: The x,y position on the screen, I'm trying to check if It overlaps another view

Answer (score 0):

String str = myTextView.getText().toString();

int lastCharPosition = str.length()-1;

Comment: Oh, not the index, the position in the parent view

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are in a custom view and you're drawing the text.

If you text starts with the view you can use

```
paintObj.measureText() + getLeft()
```

Where `getLeft()` will get you the starting position of your view.

Comment: No, I'm not drawing the text. I'm in a Textview, and I'm trying to get the x,y position of the last character....to check if it overlaps another view

Comment: Does that mean you have overlapping views? one of them is a text view and you want to know if the text inside the text view is overlap with another view?

Comment: Exactly @elmorabea

Comment: I suggest to make sure that the view are not overlapping instead.

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to overlap, I'm trying to minimize space, by making the view flow with the text

Comment: screenshot would help